# Properties bag in refinement panel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

I have some community sites and I have created some indexed properties in this sites with SharePoint Manager 2013.

I am able to index this properties so that the communities could be found in search center.

The problem is that I don't find where to add this properties to the refinement panel. I have heard that this is not possible in SharePoint 2013. Is this true? Any idea in how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone already asked me in this post [Properties bag in refinment panel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b3c29f46-b939-45aa-8ac6-0185f7491822/properties-bag-in-refinement-panel)

Comment: don't forget to mark it as answer